# rails server not reflecting changes to seed.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

new to rails and programming in general.

I have a rails app I'm working on that I cannot figure out what's going on.

My index.rb file displays a set of pins. These pins are created and stored under db > seeds.rb

When I want to add a new pin, I create it in seeds.rb and it comes up on my index.rb file (after running rake db:seed).

However, once I delete it, and rake again, it's still there and will never go away.

I can make other changes and those are reflected no problem, it's just with my seed.rb file that the issues happens.

I've tried restarting my rails server, nothing works.

This is on localhost (rails s)
Using postgresql 
Using latest version of rails

Answer (score 0):

I think you have understood the idea of seeding wrong. **It should only be used to add initial data** to the database. When you run `rake db:seed`, it will add the data you defined in your `seed.rb` file to the database, which is associated with the environment you are currently running.

So you have to truncate/delete the content of the database and seed it again to get the changes in your `seed.rb` file reflected.

Comment: ok, I'm new so that is totally possible I did confuse this. How would I go about deleting the the content in the datebase?

Comment: Login into your PostgreSQL server and truncate the table, which is storing the data. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-truncate.html

Comment: @Kenton while technically robin is correct. You could also create a small script in ruby and execute it in the console. I always prefer this method as you can make sure to keep the validations and referential integrity enforced in the ORM in tact. To run a console it is just `rails c` you can even test your script using `rails c --sandbox` (this will roll back changes on exit).

Comment: I ended up doing  rake db:reset and it worked as well.